# Javascript how to return value from function but not by return

Tags: javascript, typescript

I have method in Javascript:

```
function ServerSideDatasource(server) {
  return {
    getRows: function (params) {
      var response = server.getData(params.request).then((res) => {
        
        var result = {
          success: true,
          rows: res.rows,
          lastRow: getLastRowIndex(params.request, res.rows),
        };
   });
 }
```

Above method is called in TypeScript class:

```
    var datasource = ServerSideDatasource(getFiltersFromGrid);
    params.api.setServerSideDatasource(datasource);
```

From ServerSideDatasource I want to fetch number of rows. How to do that ?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How do I return the response from an asynchronous call?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14220321/how-do-i-return-the-response-from-an-asynchronous-call)

Answer (score 0):

You returned the function, so:

```
datasource.getRows();
```

Also, in the getRows function, return the result.

Comment: `getRows` returns `void 0`, though.

Comment: Don’t forget getRows() requires input parameters.

Comment: Yes, that comes from `setServerSideDatasource`